# Is it correct to say that $ Pr(X=x| Y=y \text{ or } Y=\tilde{y}, Z=z)\geq Pr(X=x| Y=y, Z=z) $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider some discrete real valued random variables $X,Y,Z$.

Is it correct to say that
$$
Pr(X=x| Y=y \text{ or } Y=\tilde{y}, Z=z)\geq Pr(X=x| Y=y, Z=z)
$$
?

I though it makes sense because on the lhs we are conditioning on a "larger" world. But then when I try to prove this, it seems to fail:
$$
Pr(X=x| Y=y \text{ or } Y=\tilde{y}, Z=z)=\frac{Pr(X=x, Y=y \text{ or } Y=\tilde{y}| Z=z)}{Pr(Y=y \text{ or } Y=\tilde{y}| Z=z)}
$$
and
$$
Pr(X=x| Y=y, Z=z)=\frac{Pr(X=x, Y=y | Z=z)}{Pr(Y=y | Z=z)}
$$
We have that
$$
Pr(X=x, Y=y \text{ or } Y=\tilde{y}| Z=z)\geq Pr(X=x, Y=y | Z=z)
$$
but also 
$$
Pr(Y=y \text{ or } Y=\tilde{y}| Z=z)\geq Pr(Y=y | Z=z)
$$
Could you help me to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X = Y, x = y \neq \tilde{y},$ and $Z$ takes only one value $z$ (so we can ignore it). Also assume none of these have $0$ probability of occurring. Then:

$$Pr(X = x | Y = y, Z = z) = Pr(X = x | X = x) = 1$$

However, if $X = \tilde{y}$ with any probability then:

$$Pr(X = x | Y = y \text{ or } Y = \tilde{y}, Z=z) = Pr(X = x | X = x \text{ or } X = \tilde{y} \neq x) < 1$$

So the inequality doesn't hold in general. Intuitively, it could be that the possibility of $Y$ being $\tilde{y}$ could correlate strongly with $X \neq x,$ so including that possibility drops the probability.

Comment: Thank you. If you have time could you help me with my previous question on conditional probabilities? I am struggling with them today. Thanks